# In simple words: What is channel bonding?

Tags: networking

The title pretty much says it, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channel bonding (also known as "Ethernet bonding") is a computer networking arrangement in which two or more network interfaces on a host computer are combined for redundancy or increased throughput.

Have a look at this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_bonding) for more.